# Metadata Exception on WCF Deploy

Tags: .net, entity-framework, wcf, jenkins, amazon-ec2

The overview of my project is I have a SQL database with exam information that is stored on an amazon RDS.  I'm creating a WCF web service that uses Entity Framework to access that database. This WCF is then going to be deployed on an amazon EC2 through a Jenkins pipeline using MSDeploy. When I run my WCF locally, it works perfectly fine.  It also deploys successfully and i can access the WSDL of the wcf remotely.  If i call any of the methods that utilize entity framework,however,I run into a metadata exception on the deployed WCF.

Usually this has something to do with the entity framework connection string, but like i said it connects to the remote RDS perfectly fine when i run the WCF locally.  But for whatever reason it's not working once it is deployed.

TLDR: My EF Calls in my WCF work locally but not remotely and i'm not sure why

the following is my Web Config for my WCF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="LMS1701.EA.SOAPAPI.Service1" relativeAddress="./Service1.svc"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding  name="MyBasicHttpBinding"
                  >
            <security mode ="None">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service  name="LMS1701.EA.SOAPAPI.Service1">
        <endpoint  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration ="MyBasicHttpBinding" contract="LMS1701.EA.SOAPAPI.IService1"></endpoint>
       <!-- <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:61751/ExamassessmentWCF" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>-->
      </service>
      <!-- <service name="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
       <endpoint address=""
                 binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
       <endpoint
           address="mex"
           binding="mexHttpBinding"
           contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

     </service> -->

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
       To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
       Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
     -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExamAssessmentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(aws endpoint);initial catalog=ExamAssessment;user id=******;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

The following is a stack trace once the error hits.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String
>   assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry,
>   MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String
>   path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension,
>   ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String
>   paths)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetArtifactLoader(DbConnectionOptions
>   effectiveConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(DbConnectionOptions
>   effectiveConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection
>   connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor,
>   ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory,
>   Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source,
>   Expression`1 predicate)    at
>   LMS1701.EA.SOAPAPI.Service1.GetAnswersQuestion(Int32 Questid) in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\EA-DAL-SVC\ExamAssessmentSOAPAPI\ExamassessmentWCF\Service1.svc.cs:line
>   201

This is the method called resulting in the above stack trace

```
      public List<Answers> GetAnswersQuestion(int Questid)
        {
                AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
                List<int> AnswerID = db.QuestionAnswers.Where(c => c.QuestionID == Questid).Select(x => x.AnswerID).ToList(); // this is where the exception occurs
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
}
```

This is the Interface signature for the method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetAnswersQuestionQuestID={QuestID}")]
List<Answers> GetAnswersQuestion(int Questid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the problem has been solved.  There were typos in the webconfig.